# How do I extract a spectrum from a 3D spectrum-image

Tags: image-processing, dm-script

In DigitalMicrograph I have a 3D data cube of size [X x Y x Z] and I would like to extract a single spectrum at position X/Y. 
I know I can address the sub-volume by two opposing corners (x1/y1/z1) and (x2/y2/z2).
But when I do this in the script below, I only get a LinePlot display with a single value.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
number px = 5
number py = 3

image SIblock := GetFrontImage()
number sx, sy, sz
Get3DSize( SIblock, sx, sy, sz )
image spec = SIblock[ px, py, 0, px+1, py+1, sz ]

ShowImage( spec )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution addresses the right section of the volume but as a [1 x 1 x sz] image. You could rotate the image, but a better solution is to use the **slice1()** command which directly access a 1-dimensional subvolume as in the following modified script:

```
number px = 5
number py = 3
image SIblock := GetFrontImage()
number sx, sy, sz
Get3DSize( SIblock, sx, sy, sz )
image spec := Slice1( SIblock, px,py,0,  2,sz,1 )
image specCopy := ImageClone( spec )
ShowImage( specCopy )
```

The command has 7 parameters: the source image (any dimension), the starting coordinate of the volume as x/y/z and a triplet describing the sampling: The direction ( 0=x 1=y 2=z ), the number of steps in that direction and a stepsize.

Note that my script also used `image spec :=` and not `image spec =`. The difference is, that `=` copies the values (and creates a new image) while `:=` assigns the right-handside. *spec* is just another name for the identical memory space of *SIblock*. Changing the values of *spec* would change the according subvolume of *SIblock*. My script therefore creates another image *specCopy* with the command **ImageClone()** to really creat a separate 'extracted' image.